# ATmega 328P system reseting

Tags: power-supply, current, relay, reset, atmega328p

[image]I am working on an electronic system for irrigation. The system works well when I am using separate power supplies for the circuit and the 5 V relay.

When I use a common 12 V power supply for both, the system resets and the L7805 regulator gets hot. What is the source of the problem?

[image: image of the top side of the circuit]

Comment: Doesn't the datasheet of that L7805 specify capacitors on both the input and output sides? Please provide a schematic.

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing the schematic.

Comment: The core purpose of L7805 is to get hot and consume a lot of energy - this is what the part does. As a side effect, it may also be used as a voltage regulator.

Comment: Anyway, you troubleshoot this by 1) producing a schematic 2) view the 5V supply with an oscilloscope. There is no sensible way around those two things.

Comment: Please add a schematic. Why not use an external 5 V power supply instead of an inefficient linear supply?

Comment: also maybe look at a schematic for a basic ATmega328P Arduino and you'll see components like a decoupling capacitor across the power rails of the chip and a pull up resistor on the reset pin. If either of these are missing the device could be susceptible to electrical interference.

Comment: As a drop-in replacement of the decades old 7805 you might want to consider to use a modern alternative that is internally a [bock converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter).

Comment: @nad66 - Your question has been closed for now. You haven't provided much detail about your actual circuitry. If you edit your question by adding a schematic, (even hand drawn) your question might be reopened and you may receive additional help. There are several good comments so far for potential improvements, but without more information these are just guesses.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a linear regulator. Linear regulators maintain their output voltage by dissipating the energy difference between the input and output as heat. With 12V in and 5V out, your regulator is only 42% efficient, the rest turns into heat. You have a few options:

- Add a heatsink to the 7805 to get rid of the heat produced.
- Use a lower input voltage. You can't go below 7V with the 7805 because of its dropout voltage but 9V might work. I would probably also add a heatsink even with a lower input voltage.
- Use a drop-in 7805 replacement switching converter (my recommendation).
- Just get a 5V power supply and don't use an on-board regulator.

Also, what does this have to do with your MCU resetting?

Comment: Along with the above, many linear regulators will go into a thermal shut down mode if there is excessive heat being dissipated in the device. This may be the issue for the apparent system reset. An LED (with resistor) on the 5 V line could be a simple way to visually see if this is the case.

Comment: These are good points but don't really explain why just adding a single relay coil to the total current consumption would make such a big difference.

Comment: @Nedd Or simply measure the 5V with an oscilloscope. If the part goes into thermal shutdown, it will soon wake up again when cooling and the result is a sine wave curve peaking at 5V. I've often had that very problem with LM317.

Comment: I would also add that it looks like the 7805 has no capacitors added for stabilization. If the relay runs from the same supply, it can (will) cause glitches in the supply voltage during switching that might very well cause the ATMega328 to reset.